# How/Can you use both && and || in the same if statement condition?

Tags: java, operators, logical-operators

Which logical operator get "prioritized" or "read" ahead of the other, so to say.

For example:

```
if( x=y || y=y && x=x ){}
```

is java reading this as:  One of these two: (x=y||y=y), AND (x=x)

or as: Either (x=y) or (y=y AND x=x)

Sounds like something that would have been asked or at least easy to find, but alas, "and" + "or" are keywords to Google.

Comment: Any reason you couldn't just test it yourself?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: In cases like this, always use brackets for reading clarity

Comment: Also be sure to use == instead of just = for your comparisons (is that just a typo in the question?)

Comment: @Evan, that's a very good point. What I was working on confuse me to the point of a migraine, not that I fully remember at present.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The operator `&&` has a higher precedence than `||`, so `&&` will be evaluated first.

http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/

Still, many programmers will not remember that fact.  It is clearer and more maintenance-friendly to use parenthesis to specifically state the order of evaluation intended.

Note that in your code you write

```
x=y
```

that is actually the assignment operator, not the equality operator.  Presumably you intend

```
x==y
```

Comment: Seconded on using `( )` to separate logical statements. This makes code far easier to read, and makes your meaning transparent.

Comment: Dang, you said everything I wanted to say in addition to linking the order of precedence. +1

Comment: Thanks!
I am aware on both accounts, was just asking.
Besides, x==x doesn't make much sense anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

`x=y || y=y && x=x`  can work only if both x and y  are boolean, since = is assignment, and it is equivalent to `y || y && y` because you assigned x=y in as in first operation